# Not getting the desired result using Javascript slice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am new to javascript. i have written this code but not getting the desired output

```
 $('#proceed').on('click', function(){
        var txtval = [];
        $("input[name='a'],select[name='b'],input[name='c'],input[name='d'],input[name='e']").each(function(){
      txtval.push($(this).val());

var oarr=new Array;
for (var i = 0; i < txtval.length;i+=5) {
  oarr[txtval[i]] = txtval.slice(i, i+5);
}
console.log(oarr);
```

proceed is the name of the button.on the click of that button i am getting the values of all the input boxes but because there are multiple values i broke into group of

```
["1", "kumar", "mumbai", "aur",'500','2','kushal','ahm','del','1000']
```

i got result in my console as

```
[1:Array[5]]
[2:Array[5]]
```

but i need it in the below manner

```
[1:'1','kumar','mumbai','aur','500']
[2:'2','kushal','ahm','del','1000']
```

Pleas tell me where i am going wrong. thanks in advance

Comment: its a long code unable to put on fiddle.

Comment: What your need is not a valid format, this will be `['1:1', ..`, but not '`[1: '1', 'kumar'..`

Answer (score 1):

Can try this

```
var arr = ["1", "kumar", "mumbai", "aur",'500','2','kushal','ahm','del','1000'],
    count= arr.length,
    myArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < count; i += 5){
    var temp = arr.slice(i, i + 5);
    myArr.push(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
var oarr=new Array;
for (var i = 0; i < txtval.length;i+=5) {
  oarr[txtval[i]] = "'" + txtval.slice(i, i+5).join('\',\'') + "'";
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I made a mistake. Use `join()`, not `split()`. Because it returns an array.

Comment: [1: "'1','kumar','mumbai','aur','500'", 2: "'2','kushal','ahm','del,'1000''"] this is the output i am getting

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
            var arr = ["1", "kumar", "mumbai", "aur",'500','2','kushal','ahm','del','1000'],
    count= arr.length,counter=0,
    myArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < count; i += 5){
    myArr[counter]=[];
    var temp = arr.slice(i, i + 5).toString();
    myArr[counter].push(temp);
    counter++;
}
console.log(myArr);
```

output:

```
       0 ["1,kumar,mumbai,aur,500"]

       1 ["2,kushal,ahm,del,1000"]
```

Comment: i want the first value as the index like a multidimensional array

Comment: i have updated the answer now try.It should give an array of array.

Comment: i have tried your code but getting these values [Array[1], Array[1]] in console why am i getting this?

Comment: when i clicked on this [Array[1], Array[1]] i got something like this 0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0] whats this?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just the console you're using that doesn't expand the arrays automatically.
Try this to test it:

```
var secondHalf = ["1", "kumar", "mumbai", "aur",'500','2','kushal','ahm','del','1000'];
var firstHalf = secondHalf.splice(0, 5);
console.log(firstHalf.toString(), secondHalf.toString());
```

Comment: the array contains 10 elements it is dynamically generated but it can contain 15,20 and so on.how to do in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var oarr = {};
for(var i=0; i<txtval.length; i+=5) {
  oarr[txtval[i]] = txtval.slice(i, i+5);
}
```

To print an array as string on browser console

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(oarr));
```

Output

```
{"1":["1","kumar","mumbai","aur","500"],"2":["2","kushal","ahm","del","1000"]}
```

In PHP:

Hope this will help you

```
$temp = array('1','kumar','mumbai','aur','500','2','kushal','ahm','del','1000');
$final = array();
for($i=0 ; $i<count($temp); $i+=5) {
    $final[$temp[$i]] = array_slice($temp, $i, $i+5);
}
echo(json_encode($final));
```

Comment: how to store this array in php and run it in loop so that multiple insert can happen

Comment: i want your output {"1":["1","kumar","mumbai","aur","500"],"2":["2","kushal","ahm","del","1000"]} to be stored in array.By its key which is 1 and 2  i want to run in loop and insert in database.1st value in 1st row in database